# Valgrind not giving source code line for memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am using Valgrind, version 3.19.0 on an ARM platform.
I wrote a small program that hase a memory leak; here's the source:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   char* p = (char*)malloc(1024 * 1024);
   return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with

> ```bash
> arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -g -O0 -o test test.c
> ```

Then run with Valgrind on my ARM machine:

> ```bash
> valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --verbose ./test
> ```

Looks like Valgrind successfully detect the leak, bu it gives no info about the source code. Here's the output:

```
==1221== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1221== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1221== Using Valgrind-3.19.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1221== Command: ./test
==1221== 
==1221== 
==1221== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1221==     in use at exit: 1,048,576 bytes in 1 blocks
==1221==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 1,068,800 bytes allocated
==1221== 
==1221== 1,048,576 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==1221==    at 0x4864DE4: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==1221== 
==1221== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1221==    definitely lost: 1,048,576 bytes in 1 blocks
==1221==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1221==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1221==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1221==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1221== 
==1221== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==1221== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Is it possible to get the source code line where the memory was allocated? If yes, where am I wrong?

Comment: Compile the object files with the `-g` option, and link the executable with the `-g` option.  Both are important.  You indicate that you use `-g -O0` — but you don't show the entire compilation.  If you create the `.o` file with `-g -O0` and then link without the `-g`, you've omitted the debug information from the executable, which is what Valgrind works with.

Comment: I have nothing to link, my executable is generated simply with

g++ -g -O0 -o test test.c

Comment: Curious that you've tagged the question with C given that you're compiling with `g++`.  However, the code is pure C, and the compiler may interpret the file as C and compile it as C.  Showing the command line in the question would have helped (it should still be added) — it would save me typing up commentary that is irrelevant.

Comment: honestly, the compiler I'm using is from a toolchain for the arm platform, the real name is arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi-g++. I can try to see if there is a gcc version

Comment: Would be good to try with the latest version of Valgrind, just in case.

Comment: I know I added an answer some time ago, but unluckily today I still have the same problem. I'm using Valgrind at version 3.21 and the behavior is still exactly the same as described in the question.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?